# How to access the node of elastic search and install elastic dump

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I have installed elastic search on my aws account. I wanted to test if we could migrate the indices from elatic search to s3 in the source region. However for that i would have to install the elasticdump plugin. As i a quite new to aws, i dont know how to access the node of elastic server and install the plugin. Can anyone help me.?

Answer (score 0):

Better would be create a snapshot that saves the data in AWS S3, You can refer  [configure snapshot using S3 in ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-aws-custom-repository.html#ec-aws-custom-repository) for more info.

This way you can create a periodically snapshots of your indices(More robust than doing it manually) which will be saved in S3, and everything can be managed from the REST API without having to access the Elasticsearch nodes.